# how can i delete columns beginning and ending with parenthesis in a file

Tags: shell

how can i delete columns beginning and ending with parenthesis in a file
**Expectd Input - content of input.txt**

```
ABC (BCD) EFG    
BCD (ABC) (BCD) 
DEF  BCD (ABC)  
EFG HI(JKL)
ABC EFG (HI JK) LMN
```

**Expectd Output -- content of output.txt**

```
ABC EFG    
BCD    
DEF BCD
EFG HI(JKL)    
ABC EFG LMN
```

**Just thought id add one more sample input for clarity.**

```
ABC (lll) INTEGER NOT NULL -3
EDG (FK) (lll) INTEGER NOT NULL -3
HIJ (nn ooo) CHAR(16) NOT NULL 'Not Provided'
KLM (ppp) VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL 'Not Provided'
NOP (qqq) VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL 'Not Provided'
QARD (rrr) DATE NOT NULL '1900-01-01'
QRS (sss) DATE NOT NULL '1900-01-01'
TUV  DATE NOT NULL '1900-01-01'
WXY (uuu) CHAR(1) NOT NULL 'N'
```

Comment: Just to make it clear: do you expect it to match `(ABC)` on the beginning or end of the line?

Comment: text withing brackets is possible at the end of the line but I dont expect it to be in the beginning. My input is basically a ddl.

Comment: the text within the brackets is what seperated the column name from the datatypes in this ddl.

Comment: Ah, now I see one more problem. Can the text *ever* contain parentheses? Something like `'Not Provided (abc) whatever'`?

Answer (score 2):

Usage
`awk '{print $0" "}' foo.txt | awk -f foo.awk`

**foo.awk**

```
BEGIN {
    RS=ORS=" "
}

{
    n=length($0)
    if (!n) next
    split($0, s, "")
}

s[1]=="(" && s[n]==")" {
    # it is column like (abcd), skip it
    next
}

s[1]=="(" {
    # stop printing
    f=1
}

!f {
    print $0
}

s[n]==")" {
    # start printing again
    f=0
}
```

Comment: this works perfect except that my input file unfortunately has one line like so ABC EFG (HI JK) LMN. WOuld it be possibe to get the out put for this like also as ABC EFG LMN. Thanks!!

Comment: Nice concept but it will fail to match parentheses adhering to the newlines.

Comment: @slitvinov: I am not getting the output using Michał Górny answer

Answer (score 1):

Based on the solution from @slitvinov:

```
BEGIN {
    RS = "[[:space:]]"
    ORS = ""
    eat = 0
}

/^\(.*\)$/ {
    next
}

/^\(/ {
    eat = 1
    next
}

/\)$/ {
    if (eat) {
        eat = 0
        next
    }
}

{
    if (eat)
        next
    print $0 RT
}
```

That to an `.awk` file and `awk -f foo.awk foo.txt` gives:

```
ABC EFG    
BCD 
DEF  BCD  
EFG HI(JKL)
ABC EFG LMN
```

But I think it could be done simpler...

Comment: it doesnt seem to be working for me. It is just giving me back the input as is.

Comment: @user973363: That's weird. I would understand if it'd just collapse the output (that's what POSIX awk would do) but giving back suggests it didn't get the regexp to match...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing that I can assemble is:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN { undef $<; } s/\s(\(.*?\)(\s))+/\2/cgs' foo.txt
```

Sorry for Perl but it's in POSIX and it has regular expressions powerful enough to cover the case.

Ah, and it can't handle if the file starts with a parenthesis. If it ends with one, it's fine as long as there's newline after it. If that's a problem, then the easiest solution would be to just add a temporary space.