# concatenate string between parenthesis in a file

Tags: shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how can i delete columns beginning and ending with parenthesis in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11695238/how-can-i-delete-columns-beginning-and-ending-with-parenthesis-in-a-file)

How can I concatenate string between parenthesis in a file?
**Expectd Input - content of input.txt**

```
ABC EFG    
BCD (AB CD) EFG
DEF BCD AB(ABC)
```

**Expectd Output -- content of output.txt**

```
ABC EFG    
BCD (ABCD) EFG    
DEF BCD AB(ABC)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using parenthesis as separators, you can do this with `awk` like this:

```
awk -F'[)(]' -v OFS="" ' 
  NF == 1
  NF  > 1 {
    for(i=2; i < NF; i+=2) {
      gsub(" +", "", $i)
      $i = "("$i")"
    }
    print
  }'
```

#### Explanation

`NF` designates number of fields.

- `NF == 1` means no parenthesis.
- `NF  > 1` means at least one field with parenthesis.
- Every other field is a parenthesis field as they are our separators. Thus globally substitute (`gsub`) space with nothing in every other field.
- Finally re-insert the parenthesis.